# Trouble casting Arraylist to Double in order to make an array of doubles

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I am trying to cast an ArrayList of doubles to an array of doubles. When I try to cast it using the following line:

```
double[] hist_list = hist_array.Cast<Double>().toArray();
```

I get the following syntax error:

```
Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token
```

and the error is on the first parenthesis, after the Cast. Cast() appears to be an argumentless method in this situation, so what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily convert it to a the primitive type double array, but you can easily convert it to an array of Double[], like so:

```
Double[] doubleArray = hist_array.toArray(new Double[hist_array.size()]);
```

Comment: And according to this very-recent analysis http://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/ it's usually more efficient to pass `new Double[0]` instead of a pre-sized array. Almost certainly not important, but interesting to note.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
ArrayList<Double> l = new ArrayList<Double>();
Object[] returnArrayObject = l.toArray();
double returnArray[] = new double[returnArrayObject.length];
for (int i = 0; i < returnArrayObject.length; i++){
     returnArray[i] = (Double)  returnArrayObject[i];
}
```

Comment: Ah, I was hoping to avoid a solution that messy. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately , that is how you would have to do it. I don't think you can convert it directly.